# JavaScript array.indexOf() not getting correct index

Tags: javascript

I have an array containing four element located in local storage.

```
   function rm(t)
   {   
           //   var l = localStorage.getItem("subje");
          // hide element from html page
          document.getElementById(t).style.display = 'none';
         var c = localStorage.getItem("class");
         var item = c+""+t;  // c is int and t is string
         var subj = localStorage.getItem("std-sub");
          var x = subj.indexOf(item);
           /*
          subj.splice(x,1);
           localStorage.setItem("final", subj);
            var k = localStorage.getItem("final");*/
           document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = x;
           }
```

when I executing function the value of x is showing 
29,17,7,0. but my given array have only four element.
why?????

Answer (score 1):

`getItem` always returns a **string** (or `null`). Therefore `subj.indexOf(item);` will get the position of the substring `item` in the string `subj`. You should encode and decode the array as JSON and store that in local storage instead.

See [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2010892/218196)